# Xamarin.Forms: Choose an item - change text in WP 8.1

Tags: xamarin.forms, picker

How to change the default text "Choose An Item" in Picker of windows phone 8.1 application?

```
var picker = new Picker
        {
            Title = "Text",
            TextColor = Color.White,
            BackgroundColor = Color.Black,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

This require styling the (native) WP8.1 picker